# How to extract divs and classes

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to Python, I need to get title, isbn, price and publication date for my very first crawler.

```
 <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7">
                <h4><a href="https://www.fadavis.com/product/anatomy-physiology-pocket-AP-jones-3">Pocket Anatomy and Physiology, 3rd Edition</a></h4>
                <div>Shirley A. Jones</div>
                <div>ISBN-13: 978-0-8036-5658-1</div>
                <p class="price"> $39.95 (US)</p>

                <div class="prd_lst">
                  <ul class="book_list">

                  </ul>
                 <div class="mobile_add_tocart">
                      <button type="button" class="addtocart" onclick="window.location.href='https://shoppingcart.fadavis.com/ShoppingCart/AddToCart?guid=74779e63-ccfb-454e-a6b9-b4e9f9a50793&amp;productid=10959&amp;applicationid=5'"> <span class="cart_icon sprite pull-left"></span>Add to Cart</button>

                  </div>



                   <div class="popover bottom Available_tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div>
                        <div class="popover-content">
                                <ul class="book_list">

                                </ul>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                   </div>                

                  <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
                <p>Publication Date: 10/12/2016</p>
                <div class="available active">
                  <div class="available_icon sprite pull-left"></div>
                  Available</div>
              </div>
```

Comment: Note: readers here _really_ want to help, and they know that for beginners, things are difficult. However, readers are also conscious there are a bunch of folks out there who are lazy and want free work under the guise of being a beginner. So, your job as a question author, is to differentiate your question from those other questions. One way to do that is to show the effort you have made, even though it does not work. Readers here _really_ appreciate personal effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import bs4

html = """
<div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7">
    <h4><a href="https://www.fadavis.com/product/anatomy-physiology-pocket-AP-jones-3">Pocket Anatomy and Physiology, 3rd Edition</a></h4>

    <div>Shirley A. Jones</div>
    <div>ISBN-13: 978-0-8036-5658-1</div>
    <p class="price"> $39.95 (US)</p>

    <div class="prd_lst">
        <ul class="book_list">

        </ul>
        <div class="mobile_add_tocart">
            <button type="button" class="addtocart" onclick="window.location.href='https://shoppingcart.fadavis.com/ShoppingCart/AddToCart?guid=74779e63-ccfb-454e-a6b9-b4e9f9a50793&amp;productid=10959&amp;applicationid=5'"> <span class="cart_icon sprite pull-left"></span>Add to Cart</button>

        </div>



        <div class="popover bottom Available_tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div>
            <div class="popover-content">
                    <ul class="book_list">

                    </ul>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <p>Publication Date: 10/12/2016</p>
    <div class="available active">
        <div class="available_icon sprite pull-left"></div>
        Available</div>
    </div>
</div>
"""

soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
div = soup.find('div', {'class': 'col-md-7'})
divs = div.findAll('div')
price = div.find('p', {'class': 'price'})
date = div.findAll('p')

print(divs[0].text)
print(divs[1].text)
print(price.text)
print(date[-1].text)
```

**Output**

```
Shirley A. Jones
ISBN-13: 978-0-8036-5658-1
$39.95 (US)
Publication Date: 10/12/2016
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but when I use this code for entire page it returns errors:

HTTPError: The HTTP server returned a redirect error that would lead to an infinite loop.
The last 30x error message was:
Found

https://www.fadavis.com/health_professions/Anatomy-and-Physiology

Comment: import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen

html = urlopen("https://www.fadavis.com/health_professions/Anatomy-and-Physiology")

soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
div = soup.find('div', {'class': 'col-md-7.col-sm-7'})
divs = div.findAll('div')
price = div.find('p', {'class': 'price'})
date = div.findAll('p')

print(divs[0].text)
print(divs[1].text)
print(price.text)
print(date[-1].text)

Comment: Actually, I want to get all ISBN, Price...from https://www.fadavis.com/ but I don't know how to go deeper pages so I started with a single page like:
https://www.fadavis.com/health_professions/Anatomy-and-Physiology

Comment: i cant get `fadavis.com` it don't load

Comment: File "D:\Anaconda\lib\urllib\request.py", line 532, in open
    response = meth(req, response)

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\urllib\request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\urllib\request.py", line 564, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)

  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\urllib\request.py", line 746, in http_error_302
    self.inf_msg + msg, headers, fp)

The page runs smooth on browsers.

Comment: to get all `ISBN, Price, Date, Title` from all pages is not easy how do you thing, here need to write many codes, i give you only one example

Comment: How it's possible? I have it open right now, on FF and chrome.

Comment: i don't know, i'm try to go to `https://www.fadavis.com/` and it don't load

Comment: ya, I didn't think it's difficult like that. Thanks for your time, maybe I can't finish my first crawler anytime soon.